# Java date parsing - works even in "wrong" cases

Tags: java, date

In Java, I'm parsing date format:

```
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DATE_FORMAT.parse(date);
```

This works fine for `"2014-12-31"`.

However it will also parse dates like `"2014-13-33"` or `"01-01-2014"` when in these cases I would expect `ParseException`. Is there a way to make if fail (throw an error) for the later cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set its leniency

```
DATE_FORMAT.setLenient(false);
```

The year is kind of tricky, because, with four `y`, it's parsed literally. The year `"01"` is valid. So is `"123456"` or any other numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27021116/642706) by [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) is correct.

## Joda-Time

An alternative is to use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Joda-Time complains appropriately and specifically when attempting to parse either of those strings which fail to match your expected format.

## ISO 8601

Your expected format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) is formally defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Joda-Time uses ISO 8601 by default when parsing and generating strings. So does the [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8, another alternative.

## Invalid Month

This:

```
LocalDate localDate1 = new LocalDate( "2014-13-33" );
```

…throws an [`IllegalFieldValueException`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/IllegalFieldValueException.html):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "2014-13-33": Value 13 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]
```

## Wrong Order Of Fields

This:

```
LocalDate localDate2 = new LocalDate( "01-01-2014" );
```

…throws an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "01-01-2014" is malformed at "14"
```